# Tomcat started, connection refused

Tags: 14.04, tomcat7

I have downloaded `apache-tomcat-7.0.65.tar.gz` from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).

I extracted, and started using `startup.sh` as follows

```
arul@arul-pc:~$ chmod +x /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin/startup.sh 
arul@arul-pc:~$ cd /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin/
arul@arul-pc:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin$ ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/bin
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-   7.0.65/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
arul@arul-pc:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin$
```

But, when I tried to open in browser using `http://localhost:8080/` am getting an error *connection refused*.

[image: webpage is not available]

How to solve this?

**EDIT 1**:

Result, for `ps -ef | grep java`

```
arul@arul-pc:~$ ps -ef | grep java
arul      4404  4373  0 11:04 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
```

**EDIT 2**:

Results,

```
arul@arul-pc:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
arul@arul-pc:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
arul@arul-pc:~$ cd /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/logs/
arul@arul-pc:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/logs$ ls
catalina.out
arul@arul-pc:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/logs$
```

And when I open *catalina.out*,

[image: /usr/bin/bin/java: not found]

Comment: did you check application process is running or not with given port ? what does the log file say ?

Comment: how to check it ?
`arul@arul-pc:~$ netstat -a | grep 8080` when I try this no response...

Comment: `$sudo netstat -a | grep 8080` if it do not show any result then for java `ps -ef | grep java` process

Comment: @PKumar, I updated the result for `ps -ef | grep java` in question, please take a look

Comment: Java process is not running before starting  tomcat run this commands `which java`  and  `java -version` then check the log files must be located in **/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/log**

Comment: @PKumar, I have updated the results, there is some problem think so, can you give solution ?

Comment: Any reasons why you not install the Ubuntu tomcat package?

Comment: @A.B.,  How to do that? I can't find any package as tomcat from Ubuntu Software Centre

Comment: You've got a extra `/bin` on your `JRE_HOME` variable. Does this work? `JRE_HOME=/usr ./startup.sh`

Comment: @AJefferiss, there is no file available `catalina.sh` in dir `/usr/bin/`, where to find it ?

Comment: @ARUL sorry just edited my comment, from within your tomcat bin, run `JRE_HOME=/usr ./startup.sh`, I'm use to starting tomcat with the `catalina.sh` script and only just noticed you were using `startup.sh`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install tomcat6` or `sudo apt-get install tomcat7` or `sudo apt-get install tomcat8`

Comment: @A.B., I got it by @ AJefferiss's idea. thank you for your support...

Comment: either do not have java on the system or path variable is not set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat runs `java` by creating a `_RUNJAVA` variable in `setclasspath.sh`. This is made up by appending `/bin/java` to the `JRE_HOME` environment variable. Your `JRE_HOME` is currently set to `/usr/bin`. So you need to modify the `JRE_HOME` to be `/usr` instead.

You can override it for the `startup.sh` script by prepending it like so:

```
JRE_HOME=/usr ./startup.sh
```

If you want to modify the `JRE_HOME` permanently across the system add it to, or edit `/etc/environment`.